# Nested Gallery Shortcode INTERMITTENTLY working

Tags: jquery, javascript, shortcode, gallery

I have an Expand/ Collapse plugin which, via a shortcode, can expand/ collapse content.
My expandable content is a shortcode of a gallery.

See here: http://shop.dearearth.net/collections

INTERMITTENTLY, the gallery shows up in at least the first to be expanded section, but never in the second...

**these are the plugins:**dagondesign.com/articles/expanding-text-plugin-for-wordpress and wordpress.org/extend/plugins/galleria-galleria

Any help on this would really be appreciated, of course! :)

Comment: can you give us plugin names, what you've tried. The more details you give the easier it'll be to give you help.

Comment: My guess, it has something to do with the galleries needing to be loaded on page load. and the expand collapse doesn't load all galleries.

Comment: @BandonRandon these are the plugins:http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/expanding-text-plugin-for-wordpress/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/galleria-galleria/

Comment: @BandonRandon - The Galleria Galleria plugin parses the wordpress [gallery] shortcode to create the js gallery.

Comment: @BandonRandon - I believe you are likely correct in that the the galleries need to load during page load as they do appear whenever i manage to click on them quickly, as the page is still laoding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after listening to the podcast this morning **[where Joel and Jeff talk about how "Fix my Code" questions](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-episode-88)** are too localized to **[benefit the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41262/whats-wrong-with-this-code-kind-of-questions-are-they-really-useful)** and serve no purpose to anyone but the op,  I'm going to try and answer this in a way that will be useful and beneficial to other weary WordPressors who ***scour the interwebs*** in search of a ***quick fix*** for their plugin and theme woes and leave this as a useful artifact that will hopefully be found one day and still be relevant.

## WordPress Troubleshooting 101

When troubleshooting any error or broken functionality the first thing is to try and determine what caused it to break or stop working.

1. Did it ever work?
2. If yes, you have to find out what changed that broke it.
3. Did I add a new plugin?
4. Did I change a setting that caused it to stop working?
5. Were any updates recently released that might of bonked things
6. Am I using the latest version??

   ## 7. Do I really need 15 or 30 different plugins to make my website work???

If it is a jQuery problem like the one mentioned by the op in the above question, you should first check if there are any conflicts or if the javascript is not loading in the right order.

### jQuery plugins require that jQuery is actually loaded before the will work.

#### How do you check for conflicts?

- I like to use the [WebKit Inspector built into the Chrome Browser Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/).
- If your a Firefox guy then you can use the handy reliable [FireBug extension](http://getfirebug.com/)
- Safari comes with it's built in [Webkit Inspector](http://www.webkit.org/blog/41/introducing-the-web-inspector/)
- Don't admit it to anyone but if you use Internet Explorer you can even enable [Microsofts browser developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You just right click and choose "Inspect Element" from the menu to get started.  (By the way it's also VERY handy for debugging CSS problems).

[image]

On the website linked and mentioned by the op here is what I found inspecting the DOM.

#### When the inspector comes up it shows 2 Uncaught Fatal Errors from the galleria-1.2.2.2.min file.

[image]

#### Copy and past your error message into Google

[image]

### One of the first results is from the actual Gallaria.js documentation

[image]

#### This should be your fix but I always like to dig a little deeper to see if there are any other issues.

The theme and plugins running on the site linked to in the question are ***loading jQuery 5 times.***  Not the same ***jQuery*** but different versions.  You have 1.2.6, 1.3.1, 1.4.2, the Google CDN version and even some versions where the license and version # were stripped out ***(I assume for faster loading...)***

Not to mention you are combing all theses regular jQuery plugins with a whole slew of jQuery UI plugins.

#### Here is the listing of all the scripts that were loaded when my browser visited the linked to site in the question.

[image]

The problem, is that the browser loads jQuery  then it loads an earlier version that wipes out the version before it.  Then it loads a plugin that starts to work then another version of jQuery loads and wipes out anything that was already loaded.  (Most users will just click the back button and not spend money with slow loading sites)

If any of your jQuery plugins use newer techniques that weren't available in jQuery 1.2.6 they will break, and when jQuery breaks, it prohibits any other jQuery from working after the break.

#### So whats my next step?  How do I get it working?

Most of the jQuery is being loaded from your themes library directory (is this a Theme Forest Theme or another commercial theme?  If so get a refund).  Check your functions.php file and header.php (I'm sure none of this is loaded with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) so be on the lookout for inline `<style type...>` tags and also lookout for `wp_derigister_script`

Remove every reference to jQuery and add this to your functions.php to load the WordPress version.  If your theme uses any other custom scripts register them and enqueue them like so.

```
add_action ('get_header', 'myprefix_load_jquery');
function myprefix_load_jquery() {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      wp_register_script('custom_script',
       get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/custom_script.js',
       array('name_of_script_dependencies'),
       '1.0' );
      wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
```

Now we need to apply the fix we found searching google so add this to the end of a js file or you can use this function to output it in your footer.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'myprefix_fix_galleria');
function myprefix_fix_galleria() {
     echo 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#gallery").galleria({
         width: 800,
         height: 500
});

});';
}
```

Hopefully this answer will be useful to anyone who is searching for a quick answer to fix their problem and learns how to troubleshoot and figure out why things happen they way they do.

If this fixes your problem please be so kind to come back and mark it as accepted so that when others find your question they will know that the answer given actually worked.

Comment: Beautiful! Didn't expect this! I do need the 30 plugins unfortunately. Also, it is unfortunate not all plugin devs take care to use proper implementation.. hence the jquery party going on in the background. i do use firebug, but am not awfully proficient to pick up scripting issues (mostly for styling purposes).

Comment: I checked out your site! I will definitely be hiring for yoru optimization services within two- three weeks. thank you so much fro this response. I have since switched from FF/ FireBug to Chrome..